# Help with paleography in a 16th century grant

Tags: medieval-latin, paleography, transcription

I'm transcribing/translating a 16th century document relating to my ancestors, but struggling with a few words. One in particular is proving difficult - the contracted last word on the 1st line of the supplied text. I can see sh and 3 minims, possible 'a' indicated on the 's'. Not sure what the word could be expanded to - possibly an occupation and possibly in the plural as there is a Thomas Norgate (not shown) as well as John.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Have you come across Du CANGE, Charles du Fresne, 1610-1806? His Glossarium mediae et infimae latinitatis (in 10 vols) is on line through ARCHIVE. I checked vol six for occupations beginning SH < https://archive.org/details/glossariummediae06duca/page/n247  where Shawaldres (Gall *chevaliers*) ( a yeomen farmer, I believe provides own weapons, and horse) caught my eye. Abbreviated here to Shw. Would that fit? Sing. or plural. Not quite an occupation. The page refers you to SCH also::: https://archive.org/details/glossariummediae06duca/page/n117

Comment: Haven't seen this material before, thanks for the reference.  Shawaldres seems unlikely... but you never know.  I think shopa might be taking things in the right direction.  What do you think the latin term for a shopkeeper/grocer would be?

Comment: (Not posting this as an answer because of too low confidence level) My first impression was something like ... *de waxtoneshire* ... and googling for "Waxton shire" does yield some results which might (not) be relevant for the manuscript's time frame...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your interesting question.

I think the key is the sequence  **..ptonesh..**  which suggests Northamptonshire to me.

> et Joh.is Norgate de Naptoneshir

If that doesn't seem likely, Du CANGE, Charles du Fresne, 1610-1806   Glossarium mediae et infimae latinitatis (in 10 vols) is on line through ARCHIVE. I checked vol six p.247 for occupations beginning [**SH**](https://archive.org/details/glossariummediae06duca/page/n247) and found

> Shawaldres ( *Gallic* chevaliers)

The text could be an abbreviation *'Shw'* Would that fit? Sing. or plural. Not quite an occupation. The page refers you to SCH also::: [archive.org/details/glossariummediae06duca/page/n117](http://archive.org/details/glossariummediae06duca/page/n117) which offers other possible occupations.

Comment: Hugh, thanks for your answer. However, I think the first line reads 'et Joh[ann]is Norgate de waxtone' before the word I am trying to decipher. Any further suggestions would be gratefully received.